# Windows Form Barcode Scanning Into Hidden Text Box

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms, barcode-scanner

I am developing a simple application that requires the user to scan some barcodes in a specific order. Like most (if not all), the USB barcode scanner emulates a keyboard. So, upon scanning a barcode, it will just type the text out is there a an active text box/field.

As I understand, I need an active/focused text box to receive the barcode input. The user should not be able to manipulate the scanned barcode data or enter their own data from the keyboard. Even if by accident.

The barcode scanner hardware is setup to automatically send an  keypress at the end of a successful scan, so I can detect the enter character in a keypress event so know when the scanning is complete.

Ideally the flow is like this:

1. User opens app, form label says "scan first barcode"
2. User scans, and app checks if correct item was scanned, if fail, prompt again
3. user scans next barcode and app checks if correct based on scan from step 2, else re-scan
4. repeat steps 2 & 3 until complete
5. Complete and clear form for new scanning.

Question:
How do I collect scanned barcodes into a windows form without having a  "visible" active text box and how do I eliminate the chance of a user altering the input?

Comment: Why use a textbox? If the form is active and no other control has focus, the form will get the key event. Even if it that isn't true, you can use the preview key events to intercept the text before any active control gets it.

Comment: @RonBeyer I've enabled Key Preview on my form to `true` and created a handler but the event is not firing.

Comment: @RonBeyer I've found a workaround using my tab control's keyDown event. So, I still need to collect each keystroke as it's scanned. How, do I distinguish between manual keyboard input and barcode scanner?

Comment: There are two kinds of barcode scanners, ones that act like a keyboard wedge and ones that you can connect to separately, usually through a serial port.  You got the wrong one.  Having a "scan mode" in your UI where the user explicitly switches the mode of your program from "manual input" to "barcode input" would be wise.  You simply use a dialog with a single textbox.  Crystal to the user, and crystal to your code.

Comment: @HansPassant yes, I will have a "barcode input" mode. My scanners can be programmed to usb/wedge, rs232, or some IBM protocol. I ONLY have a USB port available on the computer which is scanning. I'm limited.